# Is there a way to view full graph in rexster from titan DB.?

Tags: titan, rexster

I am using rexster on top of Titan to visualize the graph. I could view the vertices and get the edges for each of them. But, how can i view complete graph from Titan instead of just getting details for each vertex.? I will have thousands of vertices and edges. If i have to view them for each vertex, it will be really tough. Pleas let me know, if there is a way to visualize whole graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rexster's user interface isn't designed to visualize an entire graph.  In fact, you will find that when graphs get sufficiently large, viewing the whole graph just isn't possible (or useful). For now though, let's set memory/usability issues aside to answer your question.  You will want to use a different graph visualization tool, like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) to visualize your graph.  Both of those tools (and others you will find) can take GraphML as an input and using TinkerPop's [Reader/Writer classes](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphML-Reader-and-Writer-Library) you can output your graph to that format.

You asked about Rexster so I assume that you were using TinkerPop 2.x and Titan versions prior to 1.0.  If you were using Titan 1.0 (and thus TinkerPop 3.x), you could use the [Gephi Plugin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#gephi-plugin) for the Gremlin Console to help make the integration more seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Most user interface patterns have a performance issue at about the same time they have a usability issue. Developers who ask "how can I stop my 100,000 element drop down list from being so slow" may be missing the point that such a drop down list is useless for an end user, and instead should switch to a different paradigm, such as a typeahead search.

Similarly, once your graph has more than a few hundred vertices in it, visualizing it in its entirety is nearly impossible. You must move to viewing aggregate statistics, simplified versions of the graph, or much more impressionistic sketches that are really only good for seeing clusters.